# Почему в PHPStorm на диаграммах не отображается композиция?

Tags: php, phpstorm, uml

Читаю книгу М. Зандстра "PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования" и набросав тестовый пример, решил постоить его диаграмму UML в PHPStorm. В меню PHPStorm-а нашел в меню соответствующий функционал: при клике на файле правой кнопкой мыши вызываю контекстное меню этого файла -> Diagrams -> Show Diagram.

В итоге получил диаграмму: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для следующего кода:

```
interface red {}

class primary implements red {
    private $moon;

function __construct( composcl $moon){
    $this->moon = $moon;
}

public function fokkd()
{
    return $this->moon->catg($this);
}

public function getfstr() :string
{
    return " First root class";
}
}

class childone extends primary {

}

class childtwo extends primary {

}

class composcl {
    public function catg( primary $obj) :string
    {
        return "Delegation in use: ".$obj->getfstr();
    }
}

$obj = new primary( new composcl() );
echo $obj->fokkd();
```

Но почему не отмечена композиция? (закрашенный ромб, идущий от класса primary к классу composcl). Ведь в классе primary есть постоянная ссылка на экземпляр класса composcl. 
PHPStorm не рисует полноценные UML? Или в моем коде ошибка?
Какой программой или сервисом я могу просканировать проект и построить полноценную UML диаграмму для него?

Comment: поддержка UML в PHPstorm очень ограничена. В частности, composition не поддерживается - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11435

Answer (score 1):

В PHPStorm нельзя простроить UML диаграмму взаимодействия классов, увы. Для построения похожих графиков (не UML) я использую [phpda](https://github.com/mamuz/PhpDependencyAnalysis). Довольно хороший и более-менее настраиваемый и расширяемый инструмент для анализа взаимодействия классов в приложении.